# Under what notion of equality are typeclass laws written?

Tags: haskell, equality

Haskell typeclasses often come with laws; for instance, instances of `Monoid` [are expected](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monoid) to observe that `x <> mempty = mempty <> x = x`.

Typeclass laws are often written with single-equals (`=`) rather than double-equals (`==`). This suggests that the notion of equality used in typeclass laws is something other than that of `Eq` (which makes sense, since `Eq` is not a superclass of `Monoid`)

Searching around, I was unable to find any authoritative statement on the meaning of `=` in typeclass laws. For instance:

- The [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) does not even contain the word "law" in it
- Speaking with other Haskell users, most people seem to believe that `=` usually means extensional equality or substitution but is fundamentally context-dependent. Nobody provided any authoritative source for this claim.
- The [Haskell wiki article on monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) states that `=` is extensional, but, again, fails to provide a source, and I wasn't able to track down any way to contact the author of the relevant edit.

**The question**, then: Is there any authoritative source on or standard for the semantics for `=` in typeclass laws? If so, what is it? Additionally, are there examples where the intended meaning of `=` is particularly exotic?

---

(As a side note, treating `=` extensionally can get tricky. For instance, there is a `Monoid (IO a)` instance, but it's not really clear what extensional equality of `IO` values looks like.)

Comment: As far as I've always understood it, `=` in laws refers to substitution, not equality. So `lhs = rhs` says 'we can always substitute `lhs` for `rhs` and vice versa'. This also happens to be the Typeclassopedia's take on it.

Comment: @KozRoss FWIW, I believe that myself and others use "extensional equality" and "substitution" as essentially the same in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeclass laws are not part of the Haskell language, so they are not subject to the same kind of language-theoretic semantic analysis as the language itself.

Instead, these laws are typically presented as an informal mathematical notation.  Most presentations do not need a more detailed mathematical exposition, so they do not provide one.

Comment: > Typeclass laws are not part of the Haskell language
This seems to be the strongest indication so far. If laws aren't part of the language, then a definition for `=` would have to be given by some other entity like GHC or Hackage, both of which seem inappropriate.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect most folks use `=` to mean "moral equality" as from [Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.59.8232&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which you can think of as extensional equality up to defined-ness.

But there's no hard-and-fast rule here. There's a lot of libraries, and a lot of authors, and if you take any two authors they probably have some minor detail about `=` on which they disagree.

Comment: Fast and loose reasoning is only sometimes morally correct. I don't consider things like lazy `State` to be lawful monads. They're just ... convenient sometimes.

Comment: @dfeuer Could you unpack that a bit? What's up with `State` and how does that relate to moral correctness?

Comment: @DanielWagner, `x <$ undefined = x`. Yeah, it's "morally correct" in the sense of the paper, but it breaks reasoning about performance badly enough to make me think of it as not really a monad. Whenever I use its instances, I have to do a lot of ad hoc reasoning.

Comment: @dfeuer What monad law would `x <$ undefined = pure x` (assumed correction) violate if we chose a more discerning sense of equality?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **[comingstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259008/1412534)** that the equality in those laws is that of a mathematical language. But I would also say that it is in the respect of the operator `==`.

Why? Because `==` is supposed to implement mathematical equality.

For example, look at fractions (rational numbers). They can be implemented as pairs of integers with some rules. The pair `(a, b)` represents the fraction `a/b`. The pairs `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` represent the same rational number if `a*d == b*c`. The two pairs are then said to be equivalent, and we talk about an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). In mathematics we let a rational number be an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of pairs under this equivalence. In programming we instead define the operator `==` to tell if two pairs are equivalent, i.e. if they represent the same fraction.